# Why does only one of these CouchDB views work?

Tags: json, couchdb, couchdb-futon, design-documents

I have some documents in CouchDB of type: `"Person"` and of type `"Account"`.

For a straight list of all documents of these types I have created the following design document in `_design/directory_views`:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/directory_views",
   "_rev": "21-f5df9253504e66f28393f4bda360e110",
   "views": {
       "all_persons": {
           "map": "(function(doc) { if (doc.type == \"Person\") { emit(null, { 'last_name': doc.last_name, 'first_name': doc.first_name }); } })"
       },
       "all_accounts": {
           "map": "(function(doc) { if (doc.type == \"Account\") { emit(null, { 'username': doc.username }); } })"
       }
   }
}
```

This JSON validates on JSONLint and is accepted when saving the document in Futon's source view.

Futon lists `directory_views/all_persons` and `directory_views/all_accounts` as expected in the dropdown. all_persons creates the correct list of documents of type `"Person"`, however `all_accounts` redirects back to the toplevel `All Documents`, and lists everything.

Why does `all_persons` work, but `all_accounts` fail?

PS. I've experienced this behavior on a number of design documents so far. This example http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/couchdb_a_use_case.html#a-practical-example shows two views in the same design document, so I don't think that you can only have one view per document.

Comment: I'm not having any problems, what version of CouchDB are you using? What do your documents look like? Have you tried outside of futon just in case?

Comment: Hmmm... Seems to have fixed itself. I haven't updated the document at all and just tried it on the local machine - the views behave as expected. I suspect it might be a proxy server being clever. I hadn't tried a straight HTTP request outside of Futon, but that was a great suggestion that I would have told me if the proxy was getting in the way (the non-Futon request wouldn't have been cached). I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yep just confirmed it - using the view outside of Futon works perfectly. - also tried it on a non-proxied connection and that also worked. I think the proxy is caching something it's not supposed to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing your view directly (ie. outside of Futon) to see if it behaves the same way.